# jquery .not(":contains('<<any number>>')")

Tags: jquery, numbers, integer, contains

What is the best way to select an element that does not contain a number?

eg

```
$('div').not(":contains('1')").not(":contains('2')").not(":contains('3')")...;
```

Sorry chad I have worded my example wrong.

I have about 20 divs selected already, and need to then filter out the ones that dont contain a number to pass them into a function.

I have tried gettin your example to work like

```
if($(this:+'regex(html, #^0-9]')).length <1 {
```

but having no luck

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without using a plugin you can just use filter.

```
$('div').filter(function() {
   return !/[0-9]/.test( $(this).text() );
});
```

[Proof](http://jsfiddle.net/dkcJ4/1/)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of getting all fancy with selectors, you can use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter).

```
var re = /\d+/;

var $noNumbers = $('div').filter(function ()
{
    return !$(this).text().match(re);
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/3sRmt/